# Angular translation and keys with undescores

Tags: angularjs, translate

It seems to be a problem translating keys with underscores. I know it should work, I have seen examples working fine, but for whatever reason it's not working for me. My translation code looks like this:

```
<span translate=Add_Something></span>
or
<span>{{"Add_Something" | translate}}</span>
```

All I see is the translation key.

I have many places where I am using translation. Everything works as long as there is no "_" in the key.

I can provide more details, but dot know what exactly. is there a way of logging the problem somehow?

Thanks

EDIT 1:
Here is how I am loading translation tables:

```
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en-US');
$translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
        urlTemplate: 'api_endpoint?table={part}'
});
$translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('tablename');
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');
```

This happens in application config phase.

Comment: you're not giving us nearly enough code to help you...

Comment: Sure, but what exactly? The app is pretty complex.

Comment: at least some JS code, a bit of the translations, etc.